# What is the alternative request body for entity framework 4.6.2

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, entity-framework, webmethod

I am an immigrant from EF 7 to EF 4.6.2 (Never mind tho). Now, I am working in an update function. When I pass the `id` and the `data` to the `[WebMethod]` It prompts: `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<string,object>' does not contain a definition for 'name'`. My guess is, it's because of the receiver `dynamic value`, it'll receive the data as one JSON data only. Perhaps, what's the request body for EF 4.6.2? Like EF 7 has [FromBody], what is for EF 4.6.2?

WebMethod

```
[WebMethod]
public string UpdateData(int id, dynamic value)
{
      using(SomeDataContext context = new SomeDataContext)
      {
          var data = context.SomeData.SingleOrDefault(a => a.id == id);
          data.name = value.name;
          data.age = value.age;
      }

}
```

Javascript (Service)

```
UpdateData: function(id, data){
    $http.post("somelocation/UpdateData",{
    headers:{
        "Content-Type":"application/json;"
    }, 
    data:{id:id, value:data},
}}
```

Javascript

```
var data = [{id:1,
         name: "John",
         age: 19}]
service.UpdateData(data.id, data, function(){})
```

Comment: Entity Framework doesn't have any concept of *requests*.  [WebMethod] is from Asp.Net and [FromBody] is from Web API.  I don't think this question involves EF at all.

Comment: Also: there is no Entity Framework 4.6.2.  Are you confusing Entity Framework with *.Net Framework*?